# Content-disposition doesn't work on Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, http-headers

I'm trying to force a pdf file to download and save rather than be displayed in the browser.

I've set both Content-Type ("application/octet-stream") and Content-Disposition ("attachment"), but on the Android version of Chrome, it still opens in the browser. On desktop (Windows) Chrome it correctly switches to downloading the file with just the content-disposition applied.

Is there some other setting that I'm missing that can be included in my server side code to set the proper behavior? I'm needing the additional features of full PDF software rather than the simple built in viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I was only able to open PDF in browser when I opened a url that is itself has extention .pdf.

When dynamically generate a PDF using a .aspx file it never opened the PDF in browser on Android Chrome or any other Android browser. (PC, iOS did work however.)

The best solution for Android Chrome was to let it download the PDF and automatically open the PDF with the default PDF viewer app.

I used the following settings:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = "some document name.pdf"
```